# Magento 2 - custom price can not add to subtotal and grand total after add to cart

Tags: magento2, cart, addtocart, mini-cart

I want to add custom price for bundle products after adding to cart. I have used "checkout_cart_product_add_after" observer to do so. But it is adding custom price to product price, not in sub total and grand total.
Following is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <!-- Event for add to cart -->
    <event name="checkout_cart_product_add_after">
        <observer name="customprice_observer_set_price_for_item_add" instance="Custom\Shop\Model\Observer\SetPriceForItem"/>
    </event>
</config>
```

Observer class:

```
namespace Custom\Shop\Model\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Type;

class SetPriceForItem implements ObserverInterface
{
     public function execute(Observer $observer)
     {
        $item = $observer->getEvent()->getQuoteItem();
        if ($item->getProduct()->getTypeId() == Type::TYPE_BUNDLE) {
            foreach ($item->getQuote()->getAllItems() as $bundleitems) {
                if ($bundleitems->getProduct()->getTypeId() == Type::TYPE_BUNDLE) {
                    $bundle_price = $bundleitems->getProduct()->getFinalPrice();
                    $fee = $bundleitems->getProduct()->getBuildInFee();
                    $final_price = $bundle_price + $fee;
                    $bundleitems->setCustomPrice($final_price);
                    $bundleitems->setOriginalCustomPrice($final_price);
                }
            }

            $item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
        }
        return $this;
     }
}
```

> Is there anyone who can help me? Price is not adding to subtotal and
>   grand total.

Following is the cart item, subtotal and grand total.

[image]

Any help???

Comment: is this event firing?

Comment: Yes, it is firing because product price is $22.95 and I have added $40, so price price is showing $62.95

Comment: @AmitBera do you have any idea how to overcome the problem?

Comment: any Update on this...?

Comment: any update on this?

Comment: @AmitBera have you got any solution for the same ? If yes, please post here..

Comment: i did not check it again

Answer (score 1):

I had smiliar problem, but in my case, subtotal was 0 after adding the product to the cart. Try with this:

`$cart->setTotalsCollectedFlag(false);
$cart->getShippingAddress()->setCollectShippingRates(true);
$cart->collectTotals();
$this->cartRepository->save($cart);`

The missing line was `$cart->getShippingAddress()->setCollectShippingRates(true);`.
You can find same solution in `\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart::save()` method.